# Running one pipeline at a time in Gitlab runner

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a Private Gitlab runner that I use for running following stages in my pipeline:

1. vm-start
2. test
3. build
4. deploy
5. vm-stop

`vm-start` and `vm-stop` stages are used to start and stop another Runner VM in Azure, which is responsible for running `test`, `build` and `deploy` stages (flow which I control via tags)

The issue I'm facing is when 2 pipelines are triggered at the same time on the same runner. First pipeline might be shutting down the VM where the second pipeline is still on testing stage. This ultimately results in second pipeline getting failed.

I tried looking into `concurrency` option but that is only at a job level. I'm ideally looking to run only 1 pipeline at a time and queue the others. Only when first pipeline is finished completely should the second pipeline start. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

To ensure only one pipeline runs at a time in GitLab and queue others, you can use the `resource_group` attribute in your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file. For instance, you can assign all jobs in your pipeline to the same `resource_group`. This configuration makes GitLab run only one set of jobs (e.g., `vm-start`, `test`, `build`, `deploy`, `vm-stop`) at any given time for that resource group. If another pipeline is triggered while one is already running, it will automatically queue until the running pipeline finishes.
You can look further into resource groups [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/resource_groups/)